# Why doesn't window.open get blocked on a setTimeout <= 1000ms?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, window.open, requestanimationframe

```
document.querySelector('#ontime').onclick = function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.open('https://www.google.com');
    }, 1000);
};
```

When using window.open after a user click with a timeout <= 1000ms (or a `Promise.resolve().then(...)`) it doesn't get blocked by the browser.

If you do the same using a timeout > 1000ms or `requestAnimationFrame`, the popup gets blocked.

Full example with the 4 cases is available clicking the link below:
https://jsfiddle.net/kouty79/rcwgbfxy/

Does anybody know why? Is there any documentation or w3c spec about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "get blocked"? Hang the UI thread?

Comment: Because it's considered auto popup, so it's blocked. 1s is the limit (I assume). You should check in other browsers, they should have similar time limits after which popup will be considered opened automatically.

Comment: Oh, I see, "blocked" as in "not opened". I was thinking of something else entirely. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [HTML 5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#allowed-to-show-a-popup):

> An algorithm is allowed to show a popup if any of the following conditions is true:
>
> …
>
> event listener for a trusted event
>   …
>
> …  queued by an algorithm that was allowed to show a popup, and the chain of such algorithms started **within a user-agent defined timeframe**.

`onclick` is a trusted event, but `setTimeout` put it in a queue (so it wasn't called directly) so the popup has to come within a certain time.

That time is up to the browser to decide.

Comment: Thanks, that explains setTimeout. Still, why with requestAnimationFrame popup gets blocked? After all RAF gets scheduled much earlier than setTimeout 1000 ms.

Comment: Smells like a bug.